# DBMS_Snapshot.refresh not working on 11g , materialized view error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-06512

I executed `DBMS_Snapshot.refresh` on `Oracle 10g` it worked fine, but when i execute the same on `Oracle 11g` it gives the following error

```
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.refresh('Table1','F'); 

 BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.refresh('Table1','F'); END; 
 . 
 *

 ERROR at line 1: 
 ORA-23401: materialized view "localuser"."Table1" does not 
 exist 
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2558 
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2771 
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2740 
 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Any help much appreciated

Regards.

Nandish

Comment: The error looks pretty self explaining. What exactly is not clear about the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there may be many reasons for this.

1. You didn't recreate the MV yet in 11g.  You can't refresh an MV to create it.
2. You didn't recreate a synonym (public or private) to the schema where the MV is located.
3. You didn't recreate grants to the MV in another schema, so create them.

You might try DBMS_MVIEW instead of DBMS_SNAPSHOT.

```
exec dbms_mview.refresh('Table1');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that it is looking for `"Table1"` in a case sensitive manner. Try passing in `'TABLE1'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My case was little different. The DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('ABC.XYZ') call happens from a oracle stored procedure (SCHEMA1.PROC1). I was calling the SP as a different user (UserA). I have given all permissions to the user, but to no awail. Apparently, oracle dont seem to care about the permission the user has, it looks for the permissions for the package owner.. this is very odd and contrary to what I ready everywhere.. but it did work

didnt work:

GRANT ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO UserA;

GRANT SELECT ON ABC.MLOG$_XYZ TO UserA;

Worked:

GRANT ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW TO SCHEMA1;

GRANT SELECT ON ABC.MLOG$_XYZ TO UserA, SCHEMA1;